# different foreground colors for each line in wxPython wxTextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a multiline

```
wx.TextCtrl()
```

object which I set it's forground and Background colors for writing strings.I need to write different lines with different colors ,

```
wx.TextCtrl.setForgroundcolor()
```

changes all previous lines colors as well.Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several methods in wx.Python to get colored text.

- `wx.TextCtrl` with `wx.TE_RICH`, `wx.TE_RICH2` styles
- `wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl`
- `wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl`
- `wx.HtmlWindow` (inserting color tags in your text)
- `wx.ListCrtl`

You can get examples of all of them in the wxPython demo

For example, you can change fore and background colors in any part of a `wx.TextCrtl`:

```
rt = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1,"My Text....",size=(200, 100),style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_RICH2)
rt.SetInsertionPoint(0)
rt.SetStyle(2, 5, wx.TextAttr("red", "blue"))
```

`wx.richtext` is also easy to use to write lines with different colors:

```
rtc = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(self, style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.NO_BORDER)
rtc.BeginTextColour((255, 0, 0))
rtc.WriteText("this color is red")
rtc.EndTextColour()
rtc.Newline()
```

As indicated in other answer the use of a `wx.ListCrtl` can be a very straighforward method if you work with lines of text (instead of multiline text).

Answer (score 6):

If you need set color for line before inserting you can change basic properties:

```
ctrlText.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.GREEN,wx.BLACK))
#where wx.GREEN - foreground, wx.BLACK - background for text
ctrlText.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
```

Here is example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx

class ColorTextForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Colored text")

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(100,100),
                          style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_RICH)

        self.log.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.GREEN, wx.BLACK))
        #self.log.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        self.bgColor = wx.WHITE
        self.log.SetBackgroundColour(self.bgColor)

        btnRed = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Red')
        btnGreen = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Green')
        self.cbBG  = wx.CheckBox(panel, label='White')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButtonRed, btnRed)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButtonGreen, btnGreen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.onCheckChangeBG, self.cbBG)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btnRed, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btnGreen, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.cbBG, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onButtonGreen(self, event):
        self.log.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.GREEN,  self.bgColor))
        self.log.AppendText("Geen\n")

    def onButtonRed(self, event):
        self.log.SetDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr(wx.RED,self.bgColor))
        self.log.AppendText("Red\n")

    def onCheckChangeBG(self, e):
        sender = e.GetEventObject()
        isChecked = sender.GetValue()
        if isChecked:
            self.bgColor = wx.BLACK
            self.cbBG.SetLabel('Black')
        else:
            self.bgColor = wx.WHITE
            self.cbBG.SetLabel('White')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = ColorTextForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `wx.TextCtrl` is [`wx.ListCtrl`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html) which has a per-line interface.

You can set colors of the `wx.ListCtrl` with
[`SetItemBackgroundColour`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrlsetitembackgroundcolour)
and
[`SetItemTextColour`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxlistctrl.html#wxlistctrlsetitemtextcolour)